# Tensor product of the Heaviside distribution

Tags: integration, tensor-products, distribution-theory

I would like to prove that:

\begin{equation}
H_{(a,b)}=H_a \otimes H_b
\end{equation}
So far I have:

\begin{equation}
\langle H_a(x) \otimes H_b(y), \phi\rangle=\langle H_a(x),\langle H_b(y),\phi(x,y)\rangle\rangle =\\
\langle H_a(x), \psi(x)\rangle= \int_{a}^{\infty}\psi(x)dx=\int_{a}^{\infty}\int_{b}^{\infty}\phi(x,y)dxdy
\end{equation}
where $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^2})$, with $H_a(x)$ I mean that the Heaviside distribution acts on the $x$ variable and that $\psi(x)=\langle H_b(y), \phi(x,y)\rangle=\int_{b}^{\infty}\phi(x,y)dy, \psi\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

First of all, **I am not sure if that is correct**.

Moreover, I am not sure if I can identify the double integral as a consecutive integral. I know that I should be able to, but which are the conditions that have to be met, in order for this to hold?

Thank you!

Comment: Define $ H_{a} \otimes H_{b} $ on $ {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}) \odot {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}) $ by
$$
\forall \phi,\psi \in {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}): \quad
(H_{a} \otimes H_{b})(\phi \odot \psi) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\langle H_{a},\phi \rangle \langle H_{b},\psi \rangle.
$$
You then need to show that $ H_{a} \otimes H_{b} $ extends by continuity to a suitable completion $ {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}) \otimes {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}) $ of $ {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}) \odot {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}) $ that is isomorphic as a topological vector space to $ {C_{0}^{\infty}}(\Bbb{R}^{2}) $.

Comment: @Berrick Caleb Fillmore But that answers to the second part of my question, right? What about the first part? Is that, what I wrote, correct?

Comment: Formally, what you’ve written in the first part is correct.

Comment: @Berrick Caleb Fillmore ok so what remains seems to be the hard part.. Can you direct me to the correct answer?

Comment: @Mitscaype Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by $H_{(a,b)}$? Obviously $\delta_{(a,b)}$ would be the delta distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$, centered at $(a,b)$, but I'm not sure how to interpret a "2-dimensional" Heaviside function/distribution.